# Rayleigh-Taylor instability with negative Atwood number?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stability

I was reading a paper entitled "The Rayleigh—Taylor instability in astrophysical fluids" by Allen & Hughes (1984) that indicates the instability can occur for $ \rho_{01} < \rho_{02} $ which would indicate a negative Atwood number. But how is this possible? Does not the density gradient have to be opposite the direction of the effective gravity? Must not the Atwood number be necessarily positive for a Rayleigh-Taylor instability?

Comment: Might they be taking about Richtmyer-Meshkov instability for negative Atwood numbers?

Comment: The authors do not reference any other instabilities and the result they predict for the negative Atwood number is simply that expected in the classical (non-relativistic) Rayleigh-Taylor instability. No impulse is implied in their derivation (although they only consider a linear stability analysis).

Comment: hmm, I suppose the next guess from me would be that the lighter material would have to be accelerating into the heavier to ensure a positive growth rate ($\gamma=\sqrt{Ag\alpha}$). Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I believe that is similar to what is found ($\omega = (gk)^{1/2}$), but should it not be the denser material accelerating into the less dense material for the RTI to occur? i.e. the effective gravity is pointing in the direction opposite to the density gradient

Comment: Also, in the paper they observe there is a saturation for the growth rate for positive Atwood number, but no saturation for negative Atwood number (i.e. the instability remains always proportional to g). Perhaps this may help? Although the physical reasoning is not exactly clear to me.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/178516/25301

Comment: The quote "this surface is stable or unstable according to whether the acceleration is directed from the heavier to the lighter fluid or vice versa" appears to support what I've stated above, no? That the RTI only develops when there is a net acceleration in the direction opposite the density gradient. Also, to clarify, is $\alpha = 1/k$ in your above expression?

Comment: *The nature of this instability does not change when the problem is posed as a lighter fluid accelerating against a heavier one.*

Comment: That appears to be largely a matter of semantics and framing the situation as the denser fluid rising into the less dense fluid or vice versa. What I am stating is that you can observe from your above relation that if $g$ is negative (i.e. in the opposite direction), then $\gamma$ is imaginary, and so there is no longer an instability—it would only be an oscillating perturbation. If either $g$ (the effective gravity) or $A$ (Atwood number) is reversed in sign, then there is no longer an instability which I am trying to confirm as it appears to be at odds with the paper's claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; there's no such thing as a Rayleigh-Taylor instability with a negative Atwood number.  That would imply that the density of the upper fluid, $\rho_{01}$, is less than the density of the lower fluid, $\rho_{02}$, which is clearly a stable situation with respect to the R-T instability.

So how did $\rho_{01} < \rho_{02}$ appear in the Allen and Hughes paper? 
 I'm pretty sure it was just a typo.  I read through [the paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?db_key=AST&bibcode=1984MNRAS.208..609A&letter=0&classic=YES&defaultprint=YES&whole_paper=YES&page=612&epage=612&send=Send%20PDF&filetype=.pdf) and the only place I saw anything that looked like a negative Atwood number was in section 4.2.2, where there's a sentence: *In conclusion, it may be seen that the growth of R—T instabilities saturates for large
accelerations, except in the limit $\rho_{01} \ll \rho_{02}$ where the growth remains of the usual form*

$$
\omega = (gk)^{1/2}
$$

But this sentence refers to an earlier paragraph in the same section that says, *"Again, for $\eta$ ~ 1, compressibility has little effect and
$\omega^2 \approx gk$."*  Since in the authors' notation, the Atwood number $\eta$ is defined as

$$
\eta = \frac{\rho_{01} - \rho_{02}}{\rho_{01} + \rho_{02}}
$$

it is obvious that $\eta$ ~ 1 implies $\rho_{01} \gg \rho_{02}$ rather than $\rho_{01} \ll \rho_{02}$.